# textViewShouldBeginEditing is called twice in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, xcode5

I am using Xcode 5.0.2 and iPhone 5 having iOS 7.0 in which textViewShouldBeginEditing is called twice.

Is there any solution so that textViewShouldBeginEditing method is called once?

Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    if (mIsEditing == NO)
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        mIsEditing = YES;
       [mDelegate updateViewForEditMode: YES : textView];
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: use a flag, make it YES/NO on each call to this delegate. and only on YES do your processing.

Comment: I have already used a flag 'mIsEditing'. Ideally it should be called only once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  it might help you

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{

    if (textView==urtxtviewname) {

     //   do yur coding

    }
    else (textView ==urtxtviewname)

    {
      // do your coding

    } 
    return YES;

}
```